# How to add <body> class through params in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This might have been answered before, but I'm not finding any solution to my problem.

I want to change the class of body so that I can set a background image for specific pages through CSS.

In application.html.erb:

```
<body class="<% params[:home_page] ? "homepage" : "" %>">
```

In my controller I have:

```
def home
    params[:home_page] = true
end
```

And in my SCSS file:

```
.homepage {
  background-image: url("blue_sky.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, the class of body does not change. On inspection, the parameter home_page and value true is present in the parameters, so why doesn't the class of body change to "homepage"? I also tried to use an instance variable instead of parameters, without success.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed this `=` it should be like this

```
<body class="<%= params[:home_page] ? "homepage" : "" %>">
```

secondly the `params[:home_page]` means `localhost:3000?home_page=true`, while you have this from the action then it would be good like this

```
def home
   @home_page = true
end
```

then

```
<body class="<%= @home_page ? "homepage" : "" %>">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thought I had double and triple checked for simple mistakes like that.

Comment: It's happen sometimes